# ORA-01113 File 2 needs media recovery, but it's online

Tags: oracle

I am attempting the following:

```
C:\>sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> startup
```

Gives me the output:

```
Total System Global Area 1720328192 bytes
Fixed Size 2176448 bytes
Variable Size 1073744448 bytes
Database Buffers 6873088 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-01113: file 2 needs media recovery
ORA-01110: data file 2: 'C:\ORACLE\ORADATA\MYDB\SYSAUX01.DBF'
```

From my research into the issue, a lot of people are saying that if I did

```
select FILE#, status from V$datafile where FILE#=2;
```

Then it would show the status of file 2 as 'RECOVER', but instead it's showing 'ONLINE'.
Any tips?

Comment: What does that SELECT statement return without WHERE clause? I.e. display *everything* you have.

Comment: `FILE# | STATUS
----------------
1       | System
2       | Online
3       | Online
4       | Online
5       | Online`

Comment: Formatting's not great, sorry. 1 is 'System' all others from 2-5 are 'Online'

Comment: What is your RMAN saying about the situation? 
RMAN>list failure all; RMAN>advise failure;

Comment: RMAN> list failure all;

using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of list command at 07/17/2023 20:36:06
RMAN-06171: not connected to target database

Comment: RMAN> advise failure;

RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of advise command at 07/17/2023 20:36:38
RMAN-06171: not connected to target database